# Views images as label on a table

Tags: views, media, theming

I am trying to create a table in views. My main problem is that I want to have a image in the label

"CONTENT"

so far I've managed to add a space to the field and a custom class to it, and I've added background image to that field. It works but is not the best implementation. Can you point me in the right direction or it can not be done?

Thank you and keep up the good work. (i'm new to drupal but I know php css html javascript, mainly I've made small sites with custom cms and I'm moving go drupal)

Answer (score 0):

CSS is the right solution if you have a fixed set of icons you want to use. If you need full control over the images for each node, you can add an image field and use the rewrite results settings to insert the image before your field. In this case, you would hide the label altogether.